# Simulator quits unexpectedly giving error, Springboard failed to launch error: -3

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode5, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to make a basic Application with a background Gradient, Navigation Bar and a logo on it. When Launched in a simulator an error pops up, saying **Springboard failed to launch error: -3**

I am Using the Following two in code in the ViewController:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Menu";
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(257, 3, 320, 44)];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home.png"]];
    [image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 59, 36)];
    [view addSubview:image];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //Add gradient background
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer yellowGradient];
    bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: It can't be your code... something went wrong while building...
clean & build?

Comment: or just restart your simulator by quit and open it again.

Comment: @Injectios - Even after a clean built,it giving the same error.

Comment: restarting should help

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper - I restarted the simulator, then xCode,even my Mac still the same error.

Comment: you can try remove your app from the simulator and run again. It may help

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is the most technical answer but still...

Injectios is right, it's not your code (or at least my code never causes that) it's something to do with interface builder/putting files onto the simulator (from my experience).

Simply change the device that your building for and then switch back (for example, if developing for the 3.5" iPhone screen, click the 4" simulator and run, once it builds stop it and switch back to your target device) If you are using xcode 5 the list of devices is on the same toolbar as your Run and Stop buttons or go Product -> Destination

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to delete the app from the simulator and restarting the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the above answers worked. So in my desperation I finally decided to revise all warnings and resolving them. It turned out that the root of the problem was that I was sending objects of wrong type to NSNumberFormatter and other classes/objects.

So in short: revise all your warnings and resolve all of them that mention pointer conversion problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try reset the simulator

`simulator` -> `reset contents and settings`

It is worked for me